# Kafka Connect and Debezium MySQL source - How do you get rid of Struct{} in the message Key?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

The Kafka message key produced by the debezium MySQL connector are like `Struct{id=1}` rather than `1`.

My config look like :

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
name=mysql-source
database.server.name=dbserver1
tasks.max=1
database.hostname=127.0.0.1
database.port=3306
database.user=root
database.password=*****
database.server.id=1
topic.creation.enable=true
topic.creation.default.replication.factor=-1
topic.creation.default.partitions=1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=*****
database.history.kafka.topic=dbserver1-schema-history
database.history.consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="JM6MDWHYK4SKMDX6" password="Vvah2zS6bDaYAUYgYiod/iatMtEjC6vnwIuNM847JdwH+M+SSQzhxsTSI+GnjY5z";
database.history.producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="****" password="****";
```

And adding

```
transforms=flatten
transforms.flatten.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Key
```

does not work.

Then it is a problem in delete mode during the sink because the primary key column of the target database like:

```
|id          |
---------------
|Struct{id=x}|
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flatten transform takes nested Structs into a flat one. You seem to be looking for `ExtractField$Key`...

Alternatively, use JSON/Avro/Protobuf options for `value.converter` rather than `StringConverter` to remove `Struct.toString()` representations.

This will also extract the key-value pairs into data compatible with your sink connector

Comment: I solved this using `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` on both side Source & Sink of the Kafka Connectors.